# New Git repository thinks it already has files added

Tags: android, git, android-studio, repository

**Story:**
I saw that my bitbucket remote repository has not all files and I could not add them to git.

I deleted the `.git` folder and made a new Git-repository to push to a new bitbucket repository.

**Problem:**
The new Git-repository thinks it has the old files already added. I cannot add them or commit them (No changes detected). The other "new added" files are red and I can add them (green). I dont know why. (Under Project Settings -> VCS there are no other repositorys than my new one).

Comment: How did you make the new Git repository?

Comment: In Android Studio: VCS -> Import project into VCS -> create Git repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
I found another .git folder, somewhere hidden in my project directory. Git thought this is a submodule. --> Always remove ALL git folders from your project.